# Group consecutive similar items in a python list

Tags: python, list

I have a list containing different data types, say numbers and strings:

```
foo = [5,2,'a',8,4,'b','y',9, 'd','e','g']
```

Let's say I want to find all consecutive strings in the the list, and group them together:

```
bar = [ ['a'],['b','y'],['d','e','g'] ]
```

How can I do this

Comment: This has been answered (with various criteria before) - what you're effectively after is something like: `bar = [list(g) for k, g in itertools.groupby(foo, lambda L: isinstance(L, str)) if k]` - there's a fairly comprehensive post on SO for this somewhere... bear with...

Comment: Could you point me to one of the previous answers?

Comment: Yup - trying to find a good one :)

Answer (score 4):

This is a wonderful opportunity to use [`groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby


foo = [5,2,'a',8,4,'b','y',9, 'd','e','g']
bar = [list(g) for k, g in groupby(foo, key=lambda x: isinstance(x, str)) if k]
```

which produces the desired:

```
[['a'], ['b', 'y'], ['d', 'e', 'g']]
```

Comment: Umm... what's with the weird order of `k, g` and using `if g==True` there?

Comment: @JonClements Without the `if k==True` it returns `[[5, 2], ['a'], [8, 4], ['b', 'y'], [9], ['d', 'e', 'g']]`. The grouping is done based on what boolean the `key` returns.

Comment: but `if k` is fine :)

Comment: @JonClements I see what you mean now.. Sorry.

Comment: How could I add a second condition to the key part. Lets say I wanted only strings that were above a certain length.

Comment: @OJames By adjusting the `key`. For the example you mention it would be `key=lambda x: isinstance(x, str) and len(x)>2)`. It is like writing an `if` statement

Comment: @OJames The easiest solution is probably to filter out the short strings from your list before grouping.

Comment: @JonClements But then you have to adjust the `if k` as well, and you end up checking the length twice.

Comment: The downside is that ordering the conditions might get tricky. In this case, `len` has to go after the `isinstance` check otherwise errors will be raised.

Comment: @Aran-Fey nope... because you make the `k` part be the combined criteria of type of string and length > 2 ? Like Ev's lambda above.

Comment: Ahhh.... so if it is to group all strings but then filter out those from each group, then you'd put it else where.... eg: `[[s for s in g if len(s) > 2] for k, g in groupby(foo, lambda x: isinstance(x, str)) if k]`... or similar

Comment: @JonClements Oh, that might work. It's a question of how exactly strings should be grouped. For example, if `['abc', 'x', 'xyz']` should result in a single group `[['abc', 'xyz']]`, then you can't just group by a boolean.

Comment: @Aran-Fey yup... if you only want to group by len(s) > 2 strings then you use the lambda to get k, otherwise, if it's by strings in general, you then filter from the result group... OJames didn't say which they're after particularly though, but both are possible.

Comment: @Aran-Fey of course... nothing stopping one reapplying a more specific groupby to `g` again :)

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through each element in the list, if it is of type `str`, append it to `one_d_array`, otherwise, append `one_d_array` to `two_d_array`, provided `one_d_array` is not empty. Reset `one_d_array` whenever the element is not of type `str`

```
lst = [5,2,'a',8,4,'b','y',9, 'd','e','g', 3]
ind = 0
two_d_arr = []
one_d_arr = []
while(ind < len(lst)):
    cur_element = lst[ind]
    if(isinstance(cur_element, str) == True):
        one_d_arr.append(cur_element)
    else:
        if(len(one_d_arr) != 0):
            two_d_arr.append(one_d_arr)
        one_d_arr = []
    ind = ind+1
if(len(one_d_arr) != 0):
            two_d_arr.append(one_d_arr)
print(two_d_arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

Without using any import, you can do it through a good old "for loop" iterating over the elements of the lists. Here is a code working also for any type you want, not only string:

```
def group_list(a_list, a_type):
    res = []
    sublist = []
    for elem in a_list:
        if isinstance(elem, a_type):
            # Here the element is of  type a_type: append it to a sublist
            sublist.append(elem)
        else:
            # Here the element is not of type a_type: append the sublist (if not empty) to the result list
            if sublist:
                res.append(sublist)
                sublist = []
    # If the last element of the list is of type a_type, the last sublist has not been appended: append it now
    if sublist:
        res.append(sublist)

    return res


foo = [5,2,'a',8,4,'b','y',9, 'd','e','g']
print(group_list(foo,str)) 
# [['a'], ['b', 'y'], ['d', 'e', 'g']]
```